# How does the getChar function work?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary

```
private static char[] getChars(int i) {
    char buf[] = new char[32];
    int q;
    for (int j = 31; j >= 0; j--) {
         q = (i * 52429) >>> (19);
         int r = i - ((q << 3) + (q << 1));
         buf[j] = (char) (r + '0');
         i = q;
         if (i == 0)
             break;
    }

 return buf;
}
```

The above code is based on a part of java.lang.Integer.getChars(int). How did the developers come up with this "magic" number 52429. What is the math behind it? After 81920 as input this function doesn't work. does this magic number only work for a certain range of inputs, if so why?

Comment: What class does this method belong to?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose whoops,  OP updated. It's in java.lang.Integer

Comment: I only see a method `static void getChars(int i, int index, char[] buf)` in `java.lang.Integer` (JDK7 and JDK8). Puzzled ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose In JDK8, it's at line 456: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l433 *(note that it's a `private` method)*

Comment: @Andreas: Did you notice that this is another method? Not only does it have another implementation, it also has another signature! Although the code snippet is the the same as shown ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Question says the shown code is "**based on** a **part of** java.lang.Integer.getChars(int)". Question is asking about the magic number `52429`. I was simply pointing out that in JDK8, that magic number is found at line 456. And as [my answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44919369/5221149), the magic number is from a book.

Comment: @Andreas Well ... I did not say, that it is wrong. As I also said is that I swa that the code snippet is the same. But a private method `getChars(int)` simply does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you search the source code, you'll find a second instance of that number:

```
// I use the "invariant division by multiplication" trick to
// accelerate Integer.toString.  In particular we want to
// avoid division by 10.
//
// The "trick" has roughly the same performance characteristics
// as the "classic" Integer.toString code on a non-JIT VM.
// The trick avoids .rem and .div calls but has a longer code
// path and is thus dominated by dispatch overhead.  In the
// JIT case the dispatch overhead doesn't exist and the
// "trick" is considerably faster than the classic code.
//
// TODO-FIXME: convert (x * 52429) into the equiv shift-add
// sequence.
//
// RE:  Division by Invariant Integers using Multiplication
//      T Gralund, P Montgomery
//      ACM PLDI 1994
//
```

So, the answer to your question can be found in the book [**Division by Invariant Integers using Multiplication**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Division+by+Invariant+Integers+using+Multiplication) by T Gralund, P Montgomery.

Comment: Why is the max value limited at 81920 though?

Comment: @QuestionEverything As for why, read the book. Note however, that in JDK8, it's limited to `65536`. See comment at line 453: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l433

Comment: @QuestionEverything: because `81919 * 52429` just fits into 32 bits, but `81920  * 52429` does not fit anymore.